# Where is the definition of Global_NS in a BizTalk schema?

Tags: xsd, schema, biztalk

I'm trying to use a distinguished property but I get an error "Cannot implicitly convert type ... to Global_NS ... "

I've googled/bing'ed but I've found only 4 references, none of which help

I can't see anywhere that this is set  :-(

I've been trying to remove the tempuri namespaces from a WCF service and all seemed OK, until I tried to access a distinguished property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are having a namespace prefix conflict between your imported types and the property schema.

If you look at the source of your message schema check the prefix for the `imports` node pointing to your Property Schema (default *PropertySchema.xsd*) - its prefix defaults to **ns0**.

On the message schema `Schema` node check the **Imports** property collection if any of your imported/included/redefined types use **ns0** as their namespace prefix.

You can change the namespace prefix for imported types - personally I use an abbreviation of the imported type name like *cot* for *companytype*.

Comment: Not sure if this was the answer ... I eventually got it sorted, but I did a lot of messing around trying to find the answer, so quite what I'd messed up ?? 
Thanks for the response